# Render view from Zend_form

Tags: zend-framework, view, zend-form

I try it via my Zend_form:

```
$output .= $this->_view->render('admin/form.phtml'
                , array('id' => $this->getName()
                    , 'action' => $this->getAction()
                    , 'method' => $this->getMethod()
                    , 'enctype' => $this->getEnctype()
                    , 'data' => array('code' => $code
                                    , 'name' => $name
                                    , 'description' => $description)));
```

but when i `<?php echo  $this->enctype; ?>` in admin/form.phtml i got nothing.

admin/form.phtml is rendered correctly

Comment: changing render() to partial() solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choosing render just displays the output, Zend does not pass your data to the view. But Using view partials, you could achieve that.

From the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.partial),

> The Partial view helper is used to render a specified template within
>   its own variable scope. The primary use is for reusable template
>   fragments with which you do not need to worry about variable name
>   clashes. Additionally, they allow you to specify partial view scripts
>   from specific modules.